woocommerce product image upload/import programmatically
Hi Use the following code to upload/import product images to my woocommerce website. it works as it uploads the images to the server and generates thumbnails. so the file path is there to the image. the problem I have is that the image does not show in the admin media libary it shows the default image place holder. and I just cannot figure out why. and the image also does not showup under the image. even if it is linked to product via wp_post and wp_postmeta
This is the code I'm using to upload/import the images
// Define batch size and other variables
$batch_size = 200;
$total_products = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products_images");
$total_batches = ceil($total_products / $batch_size);

// Loop through batches
for ($batch_number = 1; $batch_number <= $total_batches; $batch_number++) {
    $offset = ($batch_number - 1) * $batch_size;
    $woo_products_images = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `products_images` WHERE strPartNumber='BA212120' LIMIT $offset, $batch_size");

    // Load WordPress media handling functions
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');

    foreach ($woo_products_images as $woo_products_image) {
        $imageID = $woo_products_image->Image_ID;
        $bitDefaultImage = $woo_products_image->bitDefaultImage;
        $strPartNumber = $woo_products_image->strPartNumber;
        $imgData = base64_encode($woo_products_image->imgData);
        $imageData = base64_decode($imgData);

        // Check if the attachment already exists based on the image URL
        $existing_attachment = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE guid = %s", $imageURL));
        if (!$existing_attachment) {
            // Image doesn't exist, insert it as a new attachment
            $imageFile = wp_upload_bits($strPartNumber . '_' . $imageID . '.jpg', null, $imageData);
            if (!$imageFile['error']) {
                // Image uploaded successfully, get its URL and attachment ID
                $imageURL = $imageFile['url']; // Correctly set the image URL
                echo "Image URL after upload: $imageURL<br>"; // Add this line to check image URL after upload
                $attachment_id = attachment_url_to_postid($imageURL);

                // Set the post date and post date GMT
                $current_date = current_time('mysql');
                $insert_data = array(
                    'post_author' => 4,
                    'post_title' => $strPartNumber . ' ' . $imageID,
                    'post_status' => 'inherit',
                    'post_name' => $strPartNumber . '_' . $imageID,
                    'post_parent' => 0,
                    'guid' => $imageURL,
                    'post_type' => 'attachment',
                    'post_mime_type' => 'image/jpeg',
                    'post_date' => $current_date,
                    'post_date_gmt' => get_gmt_from_date($current_date)
                );

                $wpdb->insert($wpdb->posts, $insert_data);
                $attachment_id = $wpdb->insert_id;

                // Generate image metadata (thumbnails)
                $metadata = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $imageFile['file']);
                wp_update_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $metadata);
            } else {
                echo "Error uploading image: " . $imageFile['error'];
            }
        } else {
            // Image already exists, use existing attachment ID
            $attachment_id = $existing_attachment->ID;
            $imageURL = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id); // Update the image URL
            echo "Image URL already exists: $imageURL<br>"; // Add this line to check existing image URL
        }

        // Link image to product
        $productId = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key='_sku' AND meta_value='%s' LIMIT 1", $strPartNumber));

        if ($productId) {
            // Set the image as the featured image for the product
            set_post_thumbnail($productId, $attachment_id);
            echo "Image (ID: $attachment_id) linked to product with SKU: $strPartNumber - product ID: $productId<br>";
        } else {
            echo "Product not found with SKU: $strPartNumber<br>";
        }
    }
}

I expoext that when i import/upload the images programatically that it all should show but it does not

Missing $imageURL Variable Initialization
You're referencing $imageURL before it's assigned a value. Initialize it to an empty string outside the loop to avoid potential errors:
$imageURL = '';

Using wp_upload_bits vs. media_handle_upload
While wp_upload_bits works, consider using media_handle_upload for a more streamlined approach within WordPress
$upload = media_handle_upload( $strPartNumber . '_' . $imageID . '.jpg', null, $imageData );
if ( ! isset( $upload['error'] ) ) {
    $imageURL = $upload['url'];
    echo "Image URL after upload: $imageURL<br>";
} else {
    echo "Error uploading image: " . $upload['error'];
}

